# VMware Horizon 7 Administrator Console web-UI will not load, page is blank

Tags: vmware-horizon-view

When I try to open "Horizon 7 Administrator" (URL is `https://View-Connection-Server.Corp.local/admin/#`) Chrome opens to a blank page. I am trying from the Horizon Connection Server itself, so this is not a firewall issue (plus the Windows Firewall is off as of now). I am thinking this is an SSL cert issue, but am not sure how to troubleshoot it or fix it.

- Host OS is Windows Server 2016
- Horizon 7 Connection Server version is 7.6.0

Here are some log snippets from `C:\ProgramData\VMware\VDM\logs`:

```
2020-01-19T12:54:50.490-07:00 WARN  (10EC-11F4) <Thread-2> [bp] Item enqueued on "Outbound JMS Forwarder" but there are no workers available to process it. Busy workers = 0, queue length = 8677
2020-01-19T12:54:54.394-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13A0) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-1> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.394-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13A0) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-1> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.427-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13B8) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-3> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.427-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13B8) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-3> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.722-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13BC) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-4> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.722-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13BC) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-4> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.751-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13A0) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-1> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:54.751-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13A0) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-1> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:55.471-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13E8) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-7> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:55.471-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13E8) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-7> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.456-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13C4) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-5> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.456-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13C4) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-5> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.508-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13A0) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-1> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.508-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13A0) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-1> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.772-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13B4) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-2> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.772-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13B4) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-2> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.810-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13C4) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-5> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:54:59.810-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13C4) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-5> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
2020-01-19T12:55:00.453-07:00 WARN  (10EC-11F4) <Thread-2> [bp] Item enqueued on "Outbound JMS Forwarder" but there are no workers available to process it. Busy workers = 0, queue length = 8678
2020-01-19T12:55:00.590-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13BC) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-4> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/view
2020-01-19T12:55:00.590-07:00 ERROR (10EC-13BC) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-4> [JMSTunnelSSLSocketFactory] General error occurred: Unexpected certificate: router/view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that the thumbprint for the JMS router's certificate on the Connection Server should've been registered in the secure gateway's config files on the same CS, but the certificates had expired.

I simply uninstalled and reinstalled VMware Horizon 7 Connection Server and boom, problem solved.

EDIT: After uninstalling the Horizon CS, you also must remove the **AD LDS** role from the Windows Server: first via Add/Remove, then via Server Manager. DO NOT ADD IT BACK MANUALLY! The Horizon Connection Server installs this!